# How many posts for a shed?

Tags: shed

Living in the northern side of Georgia, it's somewhat difficult to find a flat spot to build on so I have some general questions about building a shed on a slope [like this](http://www.oneprojectcloser.com/how-to-build-a-post-beam-shed-foundation-on-a-slope/) or [like that](http://www.secrets-of-shed-building.com/shed_on_unlevel_ground.html) -- specifically how many posts will I need?

My initial plans are for a basic 12x10 (biggest allowed w/o a permit) and probably a small deck (wood pile and such) and there's tons of info on how to do those ... but I can't seem to find how many posts I will need.

I won't be storing a lawn tractor in there but I do have a number of gas powered tools (chipper/shredder, tiller, etc) so is there some kind of formula or "rule" that I should follow?

Comment: The fewer posts, the beefier your floor joists need to be to handle the span.

Comment: Lawn tractors are actually not that heavy, on a weight-per-square-foot basis: probably 300 lbs over 20+ sf. Stacking wood is probably much heavier (a cord of wood can be 5,000 lbs).

Comment: mmm, good point Henry, forgot about that.  With some of the dense wood we have around here (hickory, oak, etc) I could see that

Answer (score 1):

[All structures in the US State of Georgia are required](http://www.dca.state.ga.us/development/constructioncodes/programs/codes2.asp) to be constructed in accordance with the *International Building Code* series*...the requirements of საქართველო in the Caucuses were not immediately available online, unfortunately.

General requirements for foundations are stated in the applicable code. Site specific requirements depend upon multiple factors and require soils analysis as well as accounting for whatever wind, seismic, and snow loads the code anticipates for your local.

Be aware that exemption from a permit does not equate to exemption from the building code...nor as a practical matter does the issuance of a permit or passing inspections mean that a building actually meets code...and as always the code only specifies the worst legally acceptable building.

Comment: you sound like an inspector but didn't really answer the question, nor where I could find an answer.  Do you have an idea of where to find this? ... and soil sample? really?

Comment: @jeriley The answer to, "How much rope do I need?" is "It depends." Though in this case the answer is much more objective, since it is right in the building code...and having personally wrecked clothes with red Georgia clay...in the ground as well.